Proper Forcing Axiom for $|\mathbb{P}| \leq \mathfrak{c}$
Let $\mathsf{PFA}(\mathfrak{c})$ denote the Proper Forcing Axiom (PFA) restricted to posets $|\mathbb{P}| \leq \mathfrak{c}$. I think $\mathsf{PFA}(\mathfrak{c}) \implies \mathfrak{c} = \aleph_2$, but even if it doesn't, I'm implicitly assuming that $\mathsf{CH}$ fails.
What is the large cardinal strength of $\mathsf{PFA}(\mathfrak{c})$?

If CH holds this is equivalent to MA_Cohen, since the poset must be countable. This has no large cardinal strength.

But even without that, it seems you can force this MA-style with a countable-support iteration and bookkeeping. Is that right?

@JoelDavidHamkins I forgot to mention that I want $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ to hold. As for your second comment: I haven't thought about that, but I'll take a look at it.

I am a bit confused by your notation: $\mathbb{P}\in H_{2^{\aleph_0}}$ to me seems to indicate you want the size of the transitive closure of $\mathbb{P}$ to be less than $2^{\aleph_0}$, but you say that you want the size of $\mathbb{P}$ to be at most continuum (so $\leq2^{\aleph_0}$). In any case, i think in the former case it should be no additional strength (as Joel says) while in the latter it seems to at least require an ineffable cardinal, possibly more.

@HannesJakob you're right, I was confused with the notation for $H_\kappa$. Why do you say that we need at least an ineffable cardinal?

I will try to write an answer later (if nobody does it before then), but the gist is as follows: PFA for posets of size $\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ should imply that $\operatorname{ISP}(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_2)$ holds, by arguments in Christoph Weiss PhD thesis (he applies PFA to $\operatorname{Add}(\omega)*\operatorname{Coll}(\omega_1,\omega_2)$). This implies that $\omega_2$ is ineffable in $L$. I am not sure how to show the consistency of your axiom from an ineffable cardinal.

PFA(c) has a $\Sigma^2_1$-indescribable cardinal as an upper bound in consistency strength (this is in Hierarchies of Forcing Axioms I. by Neeman and Schimmerling).

This is just a comment, but too long to be one:
$\mathsf{PFA}(\mathfrak c)$ settles the size of the continuum, this was proved by Velickovic in Forcing axioms and stationary sets. Adv. Math. 94 (2) (1992), 256-284 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(92)90038-M).
Its strength is at most that of a $\Sigma^1_2$-indescribable cardinal (i.e., an $H_{\kappa^+}$-reflecting cardinal $\kappa$). These cardinals are below $0^\sharp$ in consistency strength.
A lower bound is a $\Pi^1_1$-indescribable cardinal (i.e., a weakly compact cardinal).
The upper bound follows from Todorcevic's arguments in Localized reflection and fragments of $\mathsf{PFA}$. In DIMACS Series in Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science, vol 58, 2002, 135-148 (https://doi.org/10.1090/DIMACS/058/11). Note Stevo's notion of $\mathsf{PFA}(\kappa)$ in that paper, which I like to denote $\mathsf{PFA}_T(\kappa)$, means something else, but implies the $\mathsf{PFA}(\kappa)$ we are discussing: $\mathsf{PFA}_T(\kappa)$ means that, given any proper forcing $\mathbb P$ and any sequence $(D_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1)$ of predense subsets of $\mathbb P$ with $|D_\alpha|\le\kappa$ for each $\alpha$, there is a filter $G\subseteq\mathbb P$ meeting all the $D_\alpha$. Thus $\mathsf{PFA}_T(\aleph_1)$ is $\mathsf{BPFA}$ and $\mathsf{PFA}_T(\omega_2)$ is equiconsistent with an $H_{\kappa^+}$-reflecting cardinal.
I believe all claims above follow from the results in the two papers I cited.
Also, to give some perspective, $\mathsf{PFA}(\aleph_1)$ is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and $\mathsf{PFA}(\mathfrak c^+)$ implies $\mathsf{AD}^{L(\mathbb R)}$.

"This is just a comment, but too long to be one"  Actually, I think it is a good answer given current knowledge.

Vaguely related, while MM and SPFA are equivalent, their bounded versions differ: MM(c) strength is conjectured to be (and is bounded by) AD$_ℝ$ + "$Θ$ is regular", while (per "Hierarchies of forcing axioms I" (Neeman and Schimmerling)) SPFA($\mathfrak{c}$-linked) and PFA($\mathfrak{c}$-linked) are equiconsistent with to a $Σ^2_1$-indescribable cardinal, but SPFA($\mathfrak{c}^+$-linked) implies MM(c).
